# installing synaptic package manager from outside the repos

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, proxy, synaptic

I have been facing some problems in installing software with ubuntu software center, due to the fact that I have not been able to run no proxy for the whole system, I have tried all methods prescribed in various websites to do the same but i always get `407  Proxy Authentication Required`. So I want to install synaptic package manager through source code or .deb file which can be downloaded from the internet and then installed manually. Please post the link from which the same can downloaded and also steps to install it manually.

As suggested in one of the answers when i download the .deb package and perform
`sudo dpkg -i synaptic_0.81.2_amd64.deb` in the terminal this is what happens...

[image]

I am not able to make out where there has been a mistake.

Comment: I suggest you fix whatever whatever problem you are having that is preventing you from installing in the usual fashion. Installing synaptic is not going to do anything to help you. Please elaborate on "I have been facing some problems in installing software with ubuntu software center, due to the fact that I have not been able to run no proxy for the whole system".

Comment: @FaheemMitha I live in an environment where I am compelled to use a proxy to access internet.... I have tried the suggestions of many websites to apply system wide proxy and failed....so whenever i try to install a package using the terminal or ubuntu software center i get `407  Proxy Authentication Required` and the process does not go through

Answer (score 2):

A lot of packages that Synaptic depends on are not installed on your system. You'll need to install these first. However, installing Synaptic will not help with your proxy problem. You should solve that first, because installing packages manually is a pain (that's why package managers exist).

Make sure you've read the available resources on getting APT to work with a proxy that requires authentication, starting with [How to configure proxy authentication to work with Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77449/how-to-configure-proxy-authentication-to-work-with-ubuntu-software-center) If you can't get your proxy to work, then:

- If possible, seek support from your system administrators.
- Check all available documentation from your organization. Often someone somewhere has documented how to use the proxy with applications other than the major web browser, but it might take a bit of hunting down.
- You can ask on this site. We'll need to have as much information you can provide about the proxy: the name of the proxy software if you have it (it's probably displayed on the page that asks for your password), the exact settings you're using, copy-paste all prompts and error messages, etc.

Furthermore you're trying to install a package for the wrong version of Ubuntu. [Synaptic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=synaptic) 0.81.2 is the version in the upcoming Ubuntu 14.10. You have [`libapt-pkg4.12`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libapt-pkg4.12) 0.9.7.5, which is the version in Ubuntu 12.10. You can't mix packages from different versions of Ubuntu (well, you can try, but most of the time you'll run into dependency errors like this one).

Ubuntu 12.10 is no longer supported, and most mirrors no longer carry it. You can still obtain packages from [old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/) in a pinch, but you won't get any more security updates or other bug fixes. You need to upgrade as soon as possible. [Direct upgrades from 12.10 to 14.04 are not supported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading); normally you need to upgrade version by version or from an LTS release to another LTS release, but there's an exception: you can go [12.10 → 13.10](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaucyUpgrades) [→ 14.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrustyUpgrades).

Comment: I tried the suggestions given in the [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/77449/how-to-configure-proxy-authentication-to-work-with-ubuntu-software-center) you have posted to set proxy settings. Even after this when i try to download from ubuntu software center i get errorslike `Check your connection`...the proxy works fine in my browser.

Comment: the name of the proxy is bsnlproxy@iitk.ac.in....what do u mean by proxy software? Thank you for taking time off to write a detailed explaination.